# Definition of exponents $b^x$ (Rudin PMA)

Tags: real-analysis, definition, exponentiation

I am working through Walter Rudin's PMA and noticed he does not provide a very precise definition of exponentials. He just states that for an integer $n>0$
$$b^n=b\cdot b \cdot ...  \cdot b$$
But he omits the proofs of $b^{n+m}=b^n b^m$, etc. as well as a definition for what $b^x$ is for any real $x$ I have just read chapter 1 so am I missing out or is it true that he omits these definitions/proofs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $x^{1/n}$ is defined with Theorem 1.21 (third edition)

Answer (score 0):

(Third Ed.)

See exercise 6 chapter 1 , and the section on the exponential and logarithmic functions in chapter 8.